Stored procedure not running completely only in SQL Server Agent
SQL Server 2015, going to 22 soon. I have stored procedures that can have multiple sub-scripts anywhere from 10-50. When running the procedure from the query window everything works. When run in the SQL Server Agent some of the scripts get skipped.
Example
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
AS
    UPDATE Table1 SET Field2 = 'a' WHERE Field = 'b'
    UPDATE Table1 SET Field3 = 1 WHERE Field IS NULL
    UPDATE Table1 SET Field4 = 'z' WHERE Field = 'y'


Run just the scripts in the query window all will run

Run as stored procedure in the query window all will run
exec dbo.test


Run in SQL Server Agent and the middle script will not run but the other 2 will. SQL Server Agent has no error as it thinks everything is ok.


Recompiles don't help. This happens once a year or so and will last a couple weeks then go away.
Thanks

There is no SQL Server 2015 - we had 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and now 2022 - so which one are you on, really? Run SELECT @@VERSION in SSMS to find out if you don't know

Perhaps you mean version 15, which is 2019? But then version 22 doesn't exist, so you're instead going to an invalid version.

"the middle script will not run but the other 2 will" Tome it sounds like one of the updates is silently rolled back

Unless the scripts in question are significantly different to that shown, I am pretty sure its not possible to miss one. But you could add try catch handling around each of them to be doubly sure.

There's almost certainly some kind of error and/or rollback happening, but we can't see because you've obfuscated the procedure a bit too much. How about you show us the full procedure, along with table definitions (you can obfuscate names, not the code).

Almost certainly SQL Agent will be executing the stored procedure with a different server login+database user than you yourself use via SSMS. Do you have triggers on the table that might behave differently for different users? Could they silently rollback transactions? (Since you don't show explicit transactions here each statement will be in its own implicit transaction.)
